# Microsoft Excel: Entering dynamic number of parameters in function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a lot of tables which look like the following:

[image: Example Table]

Those are basically answers from a questionnaire I conducted. It shows the possible answers in column A (text format), a representing value I give the answers in column B (used for Mean and Median computation, see problem below) and the number of responses in column C.

The computation of the Mean is pretty straightforward with `=(C2*B2+C3*B3+C4*B4+C5*B5+C6*B6)/SUM(C2:C6)`

I can't hower get the Median right. I found that there is a MEDIAN function but the number of parameters I have to give it changes with the number of Responses. Is there something like a "useXTimes(paramter,x)" that gives parameter x times to the function? Then I could use:

```
=MEDIAN(useXTimes(B1,C1);useXTimes(B2,C2);useXTimes(B3,C3);useXTimes(B4,C4);useXTimes(B5;C5);useXTimes(B6,C6))
```

and it would parse to `=MEDIAN(1;2;2;3;3;4;4;4;4);` in my example which would return `3`, which is what I want.

Overall I am not very familiar with excel formulas and perhaps there is a simpler solution that I do not see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the median we can calculate percentile buckets and see where the 50th percentile is. That will be our median.

First, add the **total number of responses** to cell C7. The formula is `=SUM(C2:C6)`.

Next, add three columns to your original worksheet:

- Column D will hold the **percent** of each answer from the total. The formula for cell D2 is `=C2/$C$7` and you can drag it down to D6.
- Column E will hold the **cumulative percent**. The formula for cell E2 is `=SUM($D$2:D2)` and you can drag it down to E6.
- Column F will be used to check if the 50th percentile falls within the percentile bucket in the adjacent cell in column E. The formula for cell F2 is `=E2>=0.5` and you can drag it down to F6.

Your worksheet will look like this:

[image]

At this point, even without column F, it's easy to see where the median is. Cell E4 is the percentile bucket where 50% is, so the median in this case is 3.

We can use column F to find the first occurrence of the value "TRUE" with this formula: `=MATCH(TRUE,F2:F6,0)`. The result in this case will be 3, which is the index of "TRUE" in the range F2:F6.

We can use this last formula as the index to get you the actual median **answer** (the text label) from column A, like this: `=INDIRECT("A" & (MATCH(TRUE,F2:F6,0)+1))`. Put this last formula anywhere within your worksheet, the result in this case will be "Neutral".

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula:
`=MEDIAN(REPT(B1:B5,C1:C5))`
then press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`
Because it is an array formula

Comment: Your range specification is off.  Beyond that, REPT won't do what you're trying to do here.  Give your formula a try and paste an image of the result to demonstrate that it works when you perfect it.